# How can I use my own styling and html code on django forms?

Tags: html, django

I've been struggling with the concept of form styling in Django. I do not want to use any other styling aside my own styling for the forms. How do I do this?

```
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <fieldset>
            <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required="">
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <fieldset>
            <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required="">
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <fieldset>
          <textarea name="message" rows="6" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Your message..." required=""></textarea>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <fieldset>
          <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="button">Send Message Now</button>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Here is my forms.py, for reference:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
   name = forms.CharField()
   email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
   subject = forms.CharField(required=False)
   category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('Courses', 'Courses'), ('Other', 'Other'), ])
   message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Comment: Django do not force you with any styling. The code you have given is easy editable as you please.

Comment: To be honest, this answer isn't helpful. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: You just style django's form as any other form. That's all.

Comment: The code I wrote up there doesn't contain csrf_token or any other thing for that matter to indicate that "I would want django to handle this form, but I will deal with the styling". And I am finding it hard understanding what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a css file and store it in `static` folder, point to it in `settings.py` file, i.e.:

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

Store your `main.css` in the `STATIC_ROOT` that you point to.

Then in your `base.html` (assuming, that u use `{% extends 'base.html' %}` in every html template you have):

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main.css' %}">
    ...
</html>
```

In html forms you can create your own fields, but important thing is naming `id` for every field as it should be. Probably for `author` field id will be `id_author` etc. And remember to put `{% csrf_token %}` just in the beginning of your form.

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean the id in the html?

Comment: Yes. It should be exactly as Django is expecting. You can firstfuly render classic form of Django (`{% form %}` in html), then check the source for ids you need to implement in html for each field.

Comment: To give you a better idea of what I want, here's the forms.py class:

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
    subject = forms.CharField(required=False)
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('Courses', 'Courses'), ('Other', 'Other'),
                                          ])
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

Comment: Don't post your code in comments. Edit your question with it. And please, take more time before you ask anything, because your questions are very confusing.

Comment: @KrystianMaccs Whatever styling you are seeing is the plain html, no styling included.